# Variable won't update using chrome storage API in a Chrome App

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome, google-chrome-storage

I'm struggling with a piece of code. I'm new in javascript and I've been searching for a couple of days and can't find the answer.

I'm writing a Chrome App using AngularJs and the Chrome Storage API for storing two objects with information for offline usage. I have successfully written the data into the Chrome Storage and even have retrieved it, the only problem is, the variables in which I am storing that retrieved data won't update my html page.

This is the code I'm using for getting the data previously stored on with the Chrome Storage API:

```
   chrome.storage.local.get(null, function(result){

      app.headers = result.headersData;
      console.log('Headers recuperados');
      console.log(app.headers);

      app.maestros = result.maestrosData;
      console.log('Maestros recuperados');
      console.log(app.maestros);
  });
```

My html file has {{controller.maestros}} and the logs shows that the data was retrieved, but it won't reflect on the data showed.

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

shouldn't you save those two vaues in the $scope and mark your html elements to be bound to that? e.g.

```
$scope.maestros = result.maestrosData
```

Bear in mind that, given the fact that the callback is executed outside the context of Angular, you might need to wrap your assignments with

```
$scope.$apply(function() {... your assignments here...})
```

The code would look something like this:

```
chrome.storage.local.get(null, function(result){

  $scope.$apply(function() {
    $scope.headers = result.headersData;
    $scope.maestros = result.maestrosData;
  }
```

});

that should force Angular to update those values and from your HTML file, by having something like this

```
<input ng-model="maestros">
```

you should see the updates on the UI.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot men! That makes total sense.